# Co-compact lattice in locally compact hausdorff groups

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

Bekka-Mayer in their book below, in II.2 says:

If $\Gamma$ is a discrete and cocompact subgroup of a locally compact group $G$, then $\Gamma$ is a lattice in $G$.

I can't seem to prove it. Of course if $G/\Gamma$ has a finite $G$-invariant measure only then $\Gamma$ is a lattice. I couldn't show it directly.

Surely if one could show $\Delta_G|\Gamma = \Delta_\Gamma$, that would be enough as well. Note that $\Gamma$ being discrete, the modular function of $\Gamma$, $\Delta_\Gamma \equiv 1$.

Bekka, M., & Mayer, M. (2000). [Ergodic Theory and Topological Dynamics of Group Actions on Homogeneous Spaces](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/ergodic-theory-and-topological-dynamics-of-group-actions-on-homogeneous-spaces/D44A57C1D660059C5C4AA7FA8E244659) (London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/CBO9780511758898

Comment: Isn't it the definition of a uniform lattice?

Comment: It's only a lattice if $G/\Gamma$ has a finite $G$-invariant measure. How to show that there exists such a measure on $G/\Gamma$?

Comment: Look at the Wikipedia page, for example.

Comment: "Note that if $\Gamma$  is any discrete subgroup of$G$ such that $G/\Gamma $ is compact then $\Gamma$  is automatically a lattice in $G$".

Comment: Basically for a discrete subgroup $\Gamma \subset G$ you can use the Haar measure of $G$ for $G/\Gamma$ and that cocompactness of $\Gamma$ (that is the compactness of $G/\Gamma$) implies that $G/\Gamma$ has finite measure since the Haar measure is finite on compact

Comment: More precisely since the action is cocompact there is a compact set $U$ of $G$ duch that $\Gamma U=G$. Then the Haar measure of $U$ is finite and it induces a finite measure on $G/\Gamma$.

Comment: @JCAA It does induce a finite measure, I was struggling to show that it's $G$-invariant. Standard technique, by taking average? W.r.t which measure?

Comment: You do not need to take average. The induced measure is already invariant under the action of $G$ on $G/\Gamma$: the measure of  set of cosets is the Haar measure of the set of representatives of these cosets in $U$.

Comment: @JCAA I don't understand your argument. If you just push forward the measure from an arbitrary compact subset $U$ such that $\Gamma U=G$, you get something that is not invariant in general. You probably need to assume that $\gamma U\cap U$ has measure zero for every $1\neq\gamma\in\Gamma$ (and then the existence of such $U$ requires some argument).

Comment: @JCAA it's not true that it'll be invariant (easy counter-example for $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Z$). YCor is right.

Comment: @MahbubAlam:    $U$ should of course be a fundamental domain. See https://www.math.utah.edu/pcmi12/lecture_notes/gelander.pdf

Comment: @JCAA It's not there in that book. Why should a fundamental domain exists in such a case?